# Best way to force user to log in before accessing my website

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm getting started with Firebase and I would like to have a suggestion concerning the best way to force a user to be logged to use my website.

I'm building a very simple app but i have to guarantee that content can be displayed only to logged people

Thank you!

Comment: So your question is "How to display contents of a firebase app to registered and autheticated users only?"?

Comment: Basically yes, I can manage that with redirects, but is there any better way?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "better way".. of doing what? IF I had a non-auth user accessing member only content, THEN I would redirect him to a sign-up/log-in page instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `auth().onAuthStateChanged`

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start#set_an_authentication_state_observer_and_get_user_data

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
    var displayName = user.displayName;
    var email = user.email;
    var emailVerified = user.emailVerified;
    var photoURL = user.photoURL;
    var isAnonymous = user.isAnonymous;
    var uid = user.uid;
    var providerData = user.providerData;
    // ...
  } else {
    // User is signed out.
    // ...
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using PHP to build your firebase website, in php there are session tokens that can be used to auto log in. once you got a session login you could use that to redirect them to the login page if they are not logged in. here a snip of code from one of my old college projects.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['user_logged_in'])){
    header("Location: ../login.php");
}else{
    if($_SESSION['user_logged_in'] != true){
        header("Location: ../login.php");
    }
}
```

its been a while but this checks if I remember correctly the first line checks if there is no session token and the second line checks to see if that person is logged in. if either of this isn't true it will load the login page instead of the page they wanted and cause its all done in php they can't get around this. we put all this in an authentication template, I have uploaded the PHP file to google drive if you wish to example how logins are done, this is using an MYOB database so you will have to convert it but the code in here should be a good example.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_oKWU3LnpmfJg2pD5kHzYxFX2Ydl42e_
hope this helps

Comment: i'm trying to do that without php, I'm using the Auth product from Firebase